# ASP.net MVC3 getting checkbox value from HTML form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, checkbox

I have a simple form in my MVC3 site that allows users to create a contest entry.  This has been implemented and works fine currently, but a request has been made to now allow users to make their entries private.

In my Entry model I added a boolean isPrivate.  Then I figured I would change the HTML forms for create and edit to include a checkbox to specify whether the entry should be private.

I'm new to MVC3, but I figured I could simply change the action that the form posts to by including a new boolean parameter.

This unfortunately doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone tell me how checkbox values are passed from an HTML form to a post action?  This is probably fairly common, but I can't seem to find an example for this on the web.  Almost all the examples out there simple show text inputs, I can't find anything with checkboxes.

Form:

```
        <form method="post" action="../Entry/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return isValidInput()">
            <input type="text" id="EntryTitle" name="EntryTitle" />
            <div id="invalidTitle" class="invalidData"></div>
            <p id="char-remaining">(100 characters remaining)</p>

            <input type="text" id="EntryVideo" name="EntryVideo" />
            <div id="invalidVideo" class="invalidData"></div>
            <p id="vid-desc">(URL of the Video to Embed)</p>

            <input type="file" id="ImageFile" name="ImageFile" />
            <div id="invalidImage" class="invalidData"></div>
            <p id="file-desc">(200x200px, jpeg, png, or gif)</p>

            <textarea id="EntryDesc" name="EntryDesc"></textarea>
            <div id="invalidDesc" class="invalidData"></div>
            <br />

            <input type="checkbox" id="isPrivate" name="isPrivate" />
            Make my entry private.

            <br />

            (private entries will only be viewable by you and site administrators)

            <br />


            <button id="new-entry-save">save</button>
        </form>
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Create(string EntryTitle, string EntryVideo, HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile, string EntryDesc, Boolean isPrivate)
{
...
}
```

Comment: What happens if you make isPrivate a string in your action signature?

Comment: Why don't you use the HTML-helper: <%=Html.Checkbox("isPrivate") %>? It automatically creates a hidden field, in case you don't check the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add value="true" to checkbox, also add hidden input after it with same name and value=false, i.e.:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="isPrivate" name="isPrivate" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="isPrivate" value="false" />
```

If you don't want to use hidden, use bool? instead of bool (e.g. nullable)

Comment: When left unchecked, a server error is displayed when the form is posted, even with value="true".  Should I be using a boolean for my action parameter isPrivate, or something else?

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry, forgot about required hidden field in your case

Comment: Cool this works now.  So when the form posts it just ignores the second isPrivate input if the first is checked?  I would have expected it to pass the last isPrivate value.

Comment: Yes, asp.net default binding work in this way, it will use first one (and this will be also valid for get request as well). Need to say that I usually wrap incoming parameters into supplementary class (e.g. viewmodel), e.g. `public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel vm)`, where CreateViewModel contains postback parameters - this way you will also not need using additional hidden on client.

Answer (score 2):

The other option is to have hidden text field with the same name to force data in unchecked field to be part of the post. See [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked).

```
<form> 
  <input type='hidden' value='0' name='selfdestruct'> 
  <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='selfdestruct'> 
</form>
```