# HTML form ignore checkboxes and select if jQuery is loaded

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a big problem with a form and jQuery.

```
<form name="doall" method="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Sorder ?>" name="order" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Ssort ?>" name="sort" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $form_id_venue ?>" name="form_id_venue" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="objectSelected[]" value="<?php echo $userToRead[$j]['id'] ?>"/></td>
```

If in test.php i put `print_r($_POST)` I notice that the array is populated with every input value with the exception of select and checkboxes.

`$_POST` doesn't consider checkbox, radio and select input, only text and textarea.

If I disable jQuery everything is ok. Why?

Comment: What does your jQuery code look like?

Comment: Why did you name your `checkbox` `"objectSelected[]"`?  Drop the square brackets.

Comment: Checkboxes are only sent to $_POST if they are checked.

Comment: Checkbox is not in the $_POST when it is not checked.

There are more items on this in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1809494/474535

Comment: I think that the problem is this:

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/forms/uniform.js"></script>

If I delete this line everything is ok! But i lose my checkbox styles...