# serialize empty array inputs

Tags: jquery, post, serialization, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

I've got a problem with serializing empty array inputs. for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test_checkbox[]" value="test" id="test">
<input type="checkbox" name="test_checkbox[]" value="test1" id="test1">
<input type="checkbox" name="test_checkbox[]" value="test2" id="test2">
```

when none of these are checked and I submit the form (via POST), jQuery.serialize() excludes them and they do not appear in my $_POST/Serialized String.

But I need something like test_checkbox=0, when none is ticked.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply inserting this in your server code

```
$_POST['test_checkbox'] = isset($_POST['test_checkbox']) ? $_POST['test_checkbox'] : 0;
```

Would leave you with the `$_POST['test_checkbox']` variable set to 0 if none of them was set by the client. I'd recommend using a new variable instead of resetting the entry in `$_POST`, though.

Answer (score 0):

try this way
 **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/efJBm/1/)**

```
   <form id="testform">
        <input type="checkbox" name="test_checkbox[0]" id="test" checked="checked" value="true"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test_checkbox[1]" id="test1" checked="checked" value="true"/>
    <span>click</span>
    </form>
```

**script**

```
$('span').click(function() {
    var formDate = $('#testform').serialize();
    console.log(formDate);
})​
```

Now You Want Like This Way See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/efJBm/2/)**

```
$('span').click(function() {
     var str=$('form input:not([type="checkbox"])').serialize();
    var str1=$("form input[type='checkbox']").map(function(){return this.name+"="+this.checked;}).get().join("&");
    if(str1!="" && str!="") str+="&"+str1;
    else str+=str1; 
    alert(str);
})​
```

Comment: untick the checkboxes and I get console log "empty string".
thats not what I wanted :)

Comment: now check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/efJBm/2/)

Comment: Try this way also [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rgZgH/)