# Automatically update database with checkboxs that are unticked (false)

Tags: forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I currently update my database records with an input like this

```
$this->my_model->update($id, $this->input->post()));
```

(This is after I have performed a validation on all the input. The "model" also has a white_list of data to expect.)

**Problem:** if I am updating a checkbox, and it is "unticked" (i.e. 'false') - then that field is not 'posted' by the browser.

For example - if I tick checkbox_two - but leave checkbox_one unticked, $_POST shows:

```
[field_one] = "some value"
[field_two] = "some value"
[checkbox_two] = 1
```

Therefore my model will not update that field - since it is not part of the post.

The same does not happen in reverse - because a "ticked" checkbox is posted as "1" - and thus is correctly updated.

```
[field_one] = "some value"
[field_two] = "some value"
[checkbox_one] = 1
[checkbox_two] = 1
```

**Question:** Does anyone have an elegant solution to handle this, other than having to always specifically check for each checkbox?

Comment: This seems a decent solution, the one about using hidden form elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked

Comment: You can do a `$update['field'] = $this->input->post('checkbox') ? 1 : 0;` This assumes that you always have the checkbox in your form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="example" value="FALSE" />
<input type="checkbox" name="example" value="TRUE" />
```

This practice is easy and logical. If checkbox is checked, `$this->input->post('example') == 'TRUE'` else, `$this->input->post('example') == 'FALSE'`.

The latest given value of a `name=""` overrides previous, thus givin prio `checkbox` > `hidden`.

**EDIT:** this solution is equal to given most rated answer in Rick Calder's comment. I've also come to this conclusion on my own, though.