# Multi array of checkbox with php

Tags: php, html

Hi I want to use Multi array of checkbox with php , and i want to get all values in each array  checked or not checked . my problem is the array is content only the checked value .

this is  my code :-

```
  if($_POST['send']){
            $co = count($_POST['recomID']);
               for($i=0; $i<= $co -1 ;$i++) {
 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `recom` SET
 `crit1` = '".$_POST['ch1'][$i] ."',
 `crit2` = '".$_POST['ch2'][$i]."',
 `crit3` = '".$_POST['ch3'][$i]."',
 `crit4` = '".$_POST['ch4'][$i]."', WHERE `id` = '".$_POST['recomID'][$i]."'");
               }
       }


 while($recomObject = mysql_fetch_object($recomResult)){

    echo '   
    <tr>
    <td>'.$recomObject->op.'</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch1[]" /></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch2[]" /></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch3[]" /></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch4[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="recomID[]" value="'.$recomObject->id.'"/>
    </td>
    </tr>';}
```

Comment: Please explain the need for four arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

Comment: see the image that added to question .

Comment: Need more info. Do you need to look at the values by row or column? Then what do you need to do

Comment: I will add my fetch data code to the question.

Comment: @Mustafa I have fixed my answer, it worked for me, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Asok I want four arrays not one .

Comment: @Mustafa I fixed your portion at the top of my question as well. I showed the example that I tested on. Would you like me to edit my test sample with four arrays?

Comment: @Asok yes if you can .

Comment: @Mustafa Fixed. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ran into this situation before and I resolved by placing a hidden input before the `checkbox` with the same name. If the `checkbox` is checked then that value will override the hidden. This should work for you.

The second `input` always overrides the first. In this case `checkboxes` don't `POST` if unchecked which means the hidden input would `POST` a value of 0

PHP:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['ch1'])) {
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST['ch1'], true), '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST['ch2'], true), '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST['ch3'], true), '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST['ch4'], true), '</pre>';
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    <!-- Row 1 Checkboxes -->
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch1[0]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch1[0]" />
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch2[0]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch2[0]" />
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch3[0]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch3[0]" />
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch4[0]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch4[0]" />

    <br />

    <!-- Row 2 Checkboxes -->
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch1[1]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch1[1]" />
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch2[1]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch2[1]" />
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch3[1]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch3[1]" />
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch4[1]" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch4[1]" />

    <!-- And so forth... -->

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

```
[x] [ ] [x] [ ]
[ ] [x] [ ] [x]  [ SUBMIT ]
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

**Edit**

```
$i = 0;
while($recomObject = mysql_fetch_object($recomResult)){
    echo '   
        <tr>
        <td>'.$recomObject->op.'</td>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch1['.$i.']" />
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch2['.$i.']" />
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch3['.$i.']" />
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ch4['.$i.']" />
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch1['.$i.']" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch2['.$i.']" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch3['.$i.']" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch4['.$i.']" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="recomID[]" value="'.$recomObject->id.'"/>
        </td>
        </tr>';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you want the hidden fields second so you always just check the first item for a 1 or 0?

Comment: @unholyRanger Having them second means they would override the checked value. You would always get array values of false or 0

Comment: I do this but when I checked all the result is 1,0,1,0 ...etc

Comment: @Asok you will get an array `array([0] => "0")` on unchecked and `array([0] => "1", [1] => "0")` on checked if you do hidden second. If no `[]` was in the names, they would override

Comment: @UnholyRanger You are correct, I fixed it, I forgot that when dealing with arrays I had to declare the index. See my edited answer above.

Comment: @Asok Its ok , but I use it inside while loop it means each input is duplicate in the same row . hidden = ch1[0] but checkbox = ch1[1].
Do you understand me ?

Comment: @Mustafa Yeah, then you should use an auto-incrementing  variable just like your `for` loop. I have modified my answer again. See the **edit** section above

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the **same** name for every checkbox, but a different value:

```
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="ch[]" /></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch[]" /></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="ch[]" /></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="ch[]" /></td>
```

Now, to get an array where every checked box is 1 and every unchecked box is 0, after submit do...

```
if (isset($_POST['ch'])) { // assuming form method = post

    $max = 3 // set number of checkboxes -1

    for ($i = 0;$i <= $max;$i++)

    $ch[$i] = intval(in_array($i,$_POST['ch']));

} else $ch = array();
```

EDIT: to get 0 or 1 for every single checkbox, do...

```
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch1" /></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch2" /></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch3" /></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ch4" /></td>
```

Then after submit...

```
if (isset($_POST['ch1'])) $ch1=0; else ch1=1;
...
```

If you have large numbers of checkboxes, you would iterate trough `$_POST` with `foreach`

Comment: @Mustafa: Why you need four arrays? Can you explain in detail what is your goal?

Comment: See the image that added to question .

Answer (score 0):

This method will give you the checked/unchecked status along with 4 arrays

form:

```
html>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ch1[]" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch1[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="ch2[]" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch2[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="ch3[]" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch3[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="ch4[]" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ch4[]" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The following will give one of 2 arrays (for each chX) when submitted

unchecked:

```
array([0] => "0")
```

checked:

```
array([0] => "1", [1] => "0")
```

Therefore you will always have a value in the `[0]` index. Example PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['ch1'][0])){ //do check anyway
  echo $_POST['ch1'][0];
}
```