# Checking a checkbox if its value can be found in the database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

im trying to write a code where my list of checkboxes will be checked if their value can be found within my database

this is how my form looks like

```
author name:______________
check the categories the author will handle
■ sports
■ comics
■ movies
■ ads
```

once i go to my edit author page this is how it should look like

```
author name:Lorem
check the categories the author will handle
✓ sports
■ comics
✓ movies
■ ads
```

this is how my database looks like

author.sql

```
UID      auth_name
5        Lorem
6        Ipsum
7        Dolor
8        Sit
9        Amet
```

news.sql

```
 UID     title     date     
 1       sports    1/1/2013
 2       comics    2/2/2013
 3       movies    3/3/2013
 4       ads       4/4/2013
```

and this is how i want my other table to look like once i submit my form

newscheckbox.sql

```
author_id    newstitle_id    checked
5            1               yes
6            1               yes
7            1               no
8            1               yes
9            1               no
```

---

here is my code(the problem with this code is that it only inserts those with a check on it. so my newscheckbox table looks like this)

newscheckbox.sql

```
author_id    newstitle_id    checked
5            1               yes
6            1               yes
8            1               yes
```

the checkboxes without a check isnt inserted into the database with a no in the checked column

addauthor.php(view)

```
<?php
    $attributes = array('class' => 'form form-horizontal','id'=>'form_auth','name'=>'form_auth');
    echo form_open(base_url() . 'auth/submit_auth', $attributes);
?> 
<input type="text" class="w300" name="auth_name" id="auth_name">

<?php
    foreach($auth->result() as $a)
    {
        ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" value="<?php echo $a->UID; ?>"> DJ <?php echo $a->auth_name;?>

                <?php
            }
        ?>
</form>
```

controller

```
public function auth_edit($id)
{
    $data['auth'] = $this->jivecms_model->get_auth();
    $data['news'] = $this->jivecms_model->get_news($id);
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view('auth/auth_edit');
}

public function submit_auth()
{
$this->jivecms_model->submit_auth();
redirect(base_url() . "auth/auth_edit");
}
```

model

```
function submit_auth()
{                   
    $auth_name = $this->input->post("auth_name");
    $cats = $this->input->post("cats");

    $newdata = array('auth_name'=>$auth_name
                    );


    $this->db->insert('author', $newdata); 
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();

    foreach($cats as $c)
    {
        if ($c == ""){$check="no";}
        else{$check="yes";}
        $auth = array('news_id'=>$c,'author_id'=>$id,'checked'=>$check);
        $this->db->insert('newscheckbox', $auth); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to ask.

[Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

Unchecked checkboxes are not submitted in a form post. Therefore you'd have to iterate though all possible checkboxes (not $cats) to determine if it is set.