# UncheckAll not updated Form?

Tags: jquery

When I am check multiple checkboxes form jQuery dialog box form updated i used the below code

```
$(".chk").prop('checked', true);
```

and the same code when i click UncheckAll not removed checked attribute i used the below code

```
$('.chk:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

then i changed to

```
$(".chk").val(0);
$(".chk").removeAttr("checked"); 
console.log(this);
```

Here remove all checked attribute but when i submit the form that form not updated the same thing click CheckAll working fine but UncheckAll not working
what is problem

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="meters" name="iDs" value="0" ></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="meters" name="iDs" value="0" ></input>
```

In my jps page multiple elements are there with name ids

In From class property like

Integer[] iDs;

This form maintain in session When click UncheckAll Button remove all Checked attributes and values is set to 0 the code is above when submit form using @ModelAttribute from property iDs like [2,3,5] previous values maintain i am expecting [0] array

When Click CheckAll updated form the result array in my Form calss is like iDs = [1,2,3,4,5]

When UncheckAll not working what is problem

I am using jquery 1.9.1 api

finally i tryed this but in from class having a property like Integer[] iDs  so not bind

Comment: The question is really hard to understand.Can you please make it a bit better :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to update your `input`'s name to `Ids[]`:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="meters" name="Ids[]" value="0" ></input>
```

That way it will be sent as array.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that when you uncheck a checkbox, its value is not sent in http-request. So I guess your client-side code works just fine. And you have to give a thorough look at your server-side code.
Perhaps, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992745/1492792) could be of some help to you.