# (PHP) How to set default value to unchecked checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I'm new to PHP.

Now I face this problem about the checkbox value. I search the answer from these pages which their solutions are not working to my case.

[Trying to set default checkbox value if not checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688968/trying-to-set-default-checkbox-value-if-not-checked)

[Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked) (I don't know where to put the JS with)

[how do I get all checkbox variables even if not checked from HTML to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944019/how-do-i-get-all-checkbox-variables-even-if-not-checked-from-html-to-php)

These are my codes so far...

```
<form method="POST" action="testinsertskill.php">

<br><br>Required Skills : 

**//skip the sql parts because there is no problem from calling the data from database**

<?php
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

?>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_skills" name="skills[]" value="0" />
<br /><input type="checkbox" id="skills" name="skills[]" value="1" /><?php echo $row2['Skill_Name']; ?><br />

<?php
$count++;
}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?=$count?>" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm">

</form>
```

And this is testinsertskill.php page

```
<?php session_start();

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "rootroot";
        $dbname = "onlinerecruitment";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 


$skill = $_POST['skills'];
$count = $_POST['counter'];


for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO applicant_skill VALUES('".$skill[$i]."')"; 

        $resultt = "";

        if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
           $resultt = "FINISH";
        } else {
           $resultt = "ERROR";
        }

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Assume that there are 5 skills to select and I select 2nd and 4th.

Expected result should be (0,1,0,1,0) in database but it turns out (0,0,1,0,0) because of hidden input. Now I don't know what to do because those links I referred cannot solved my problem or I don't know where I have to put it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have also some Skill_Id then code could look like this

```
<form method="POST" action="testinsertskill.php">

<br><br>Required Skills : 

**//skip the sql parts because there is no problem from calling the data from database**

<?php
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

?>
<input type="hidden" name="skills[<?= $row2['Skill_Id'] ?>]" value="0" />
<br /><input type="checkbox" name="skills[<?= $row2['Skill_Id'] ?>]" value="1" /><?= $row2['Skill_Name'] ?><br />

<?php
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm">

</form>
```

And then insert code:

```
//....
foreach($_POST['skills'] as $skillId => $skill){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO applicant_skill VALUES('".$skill."')"; 

        $resultt = "";

        if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
           $resultt = "FINISH";
        } else {
           $resultt = "ERROR";
        }

}
```

Comment: i have continue question. what if i want to INSERT the value of Skill_ID as well?