# submit data as an json array

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

**HTML :**

```
<tr v-for="role in menu.roles" v-bind:key="role.id">
    <td>{{role.name}}</td>
    <td v-for="action in actions" :key="action.id">
        <input type="checkbox" name="actions_id" :value="action.id" :label="action.name" v-model="form.actions.actions_id.actions_id">
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want that if I select `3` it saves into the database.

```
 public function updateMenuRoles(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $form = Action::create(array($id));

        return $form;
    }
```

**Note :** The form is not a create form, it is an update form so when you click edit and you saves the data but if you make changes to the checkbox by checking maybe one or two and then you click submit it generates another data in the database.

What I want is for it to update the previous one generated instead of always creating new record

**Controller :**

```
public function updateRole(Request $request, $id)
    {
        
        $form = $this->accesscontrolRepository->updateMenuRoles($request, $id);

        $form->actions_id = $request->actions_id;

        $form->update();

        return response()->json();
    }
```

For the prepopulate currently i have this in my repository

```
public function getAllActions()
    {
        $allactions = Action::first();

        return $allactions;
    }
```

and this

```
public function editRole($id)
    {
        $menurole = $this->accesscontrolRepository->getMenuRoles($id);

        $allactions = $this->accesscontrolRepository->getAllActions();


        $actionHelper = actions();

        return response()->json([
            'menurole' =>$menurole,
            'actions' => $actionHelper,
            'allactions' => $allactions,
        ]);
    }
```

in my controller but the problem is that if i click update after making edit to the checkbox the new updated checkbox is not checked which is because of the `first()` in the repository

**NOTE:**
The thing is about checking a box and creating a record of the checked boxes and if i uncheck and check the boxes, it should update that same record and not create a new one if the record already exists.

The code in which i posted above keeps creating new record for every check/uncheck boxes

For example
i have no record in the table so i click 3 checkboxes which creates a record right?
so when i go back to uncheck those check boxes a new record is created which i want to avoid because fetching the record would be difficult if it keeps creating new record

Comment: In `updateMenuRoles()` you always call `create`. Do you need a default value for the inputs? An unchecked checkbox does not have a value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to set default checkbox value if not checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688968/trying-to-set-default-checkbox-value-if-not-checked)

Comment: @PeterKrebs Yeah that is in PHP but how do i do this with VueJs?

Comment: That's not PHP specific. That's how HTML checkboxes work. Just make the HTML the same as in the question - a hidden field with the same name before the checkbox.