# Update a list of objects in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an array of objects @website_links in the view and want to update them,
but when i send to the controller action i get a list of only checked fields,
how to get the whole object's list(checked and unchecked)? 
And how can i properly update them inside update action?

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => 'website_links', :action => 'update', method: "put") do %>
    <%- @website_links.each do |link| %>
       <%= link.link %> 
       <%=  check_box_tag "checked[]", 1, link.checked"  %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Aydar, maybe you want to explain a little bit more what exactly you want to do / how you want to update them in the controller. Are @website_links ActiveRecord Models?

To solve the unchecked checkbox issue, you might want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked

Comment: Hi trueunlessfalse, yes, @website_links are ActiveRecord Models, I want to pass an array of link.id and link.checked value to the update action and update the objects by link.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the form and input helpers in combination with an ActiveRecord model. Instead, you are using form helpers that end with `_tag` to generate a *dumb* form.

I will assume that website_links is an ActiveRecord model.

To create a smarter form, in this case it may be necessary to take the parent object of all those website_links. This way, all those website links have a common parent to refer to.

In this case lets pretend that there is a model called `Website` that will act as the parent. This Website `has_many :website_links` and of course WebsiteLink `belongs_to :website`.

Let's create a form for the `Website` model to be rendered when the url `website/45/edit` is called. Leave the default code that is generated for the `update` method in the `website_controller`.

```
<%= form_for @website do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :website_name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :website_links do |subform| %>
    <%= subform.object.link_name %>
    <%= subform.check_box :checked %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Also, add this line to the `Website` model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :website_links, allow_destroy: true
```

This allows the website model to take parameters for the associated website_links and update those links.

Note that I have not tested this code and it may not suit your needs. Perhaps you need to add and remove links too. Some good explanation can also be found in this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised).

Comment: `<%= f.fields_for :website_links do |subform| %>`
how can i show filtered website_links by boolean :external field(external or internal link) here?

Comment: i just figure out that I can add filtered objects `<%= f.fields_for :website_links, @website_links do |subform| %>`