# PHP gather all checkboxes and sort checked vs unchecked

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, multiple-value

I'm working on a HTML form that contains a ton of checkboxes.  I would like to use PHP to create 2 variables.  One variable that contains the values of all the checked checkboxes and another variable one that contains the values of all the unchecked checkboxes.  Does any one know the best way to do something like this?

My idea is I would like PHP to report back in its results all the checked and unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

Comment: unchecked checkboxes do NOT get submitted with the form. unless you record what checkboxes were sent to the client when the form was generated, or have client-side code (e.g. javascript) to do something on that side, there is no way for PHP to know was NOT checked in the form. it can only see what WAS checked.

Comment: Impossible without the use of javascript.