# Can't figure out what's wrong with this for loop also array_filter maybe being funny

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, textbox, array-filter

I have a table of checkboxes and textboxes that is generated from a database. When i check 2 out of 3 checkboxes and write in 2 out of 3 textboxes. Checkbox array has 2 elements and textbox array has 3. I tried to use array_filter but it doesn't work or something...

```
$textbox_array=array_filter($_POST['text']);
$checkbox_array = $_POST['check'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($checkbox_array); $i++) {
        $textbox = $textbox_array[$i];
        $checkbox = $checkbox_array[$i];

        echo $textbox; 
        echo '-'; 
        echo $checkbox;
    }
```

i check checkboxes 9 and 10, and put values 1 and 2.

this is what i get: 1-9-10
i should get:1-2-9-10

Help me please.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are NOT sent in post data, this is the expected behavior. If for some reason you need them sent, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked

Comment: I don't need them sent also I don't need the empty textboxes to be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that with [`array_filter()` -> `Array keys are preserved`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

You need to call `array_values()` to reset the array keys -> [`array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically`](http://php.net/array_values)

```
$textbox_array=array_filter($_POST['text']);          
$textbox_array=array_values($textbox_array);
$checkbox_array = $_POST['check'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($checkbox_array); $i++) {
        $textbox = $textbox_array[$i];
        $checkbox = $checkbox_array[$i];

        echo $textbox; 
        echo '-'; 
        echo $checkbox;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Holy hell. My head exploded several times. :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $textbox_array does not have the same array keys as $checkbox_array.

One fix is to reset the array keys of $textbox_array.

Instead of

```
$textbox_array=array_filter($_POST['text']);
```

Try

```
$textbox_array=array_values(array_filter($_POST['text']));
```

Comment: @James looks like we were 3 seconds apart with the same answer. +1