# POST unchecked checkbox, doesnt work

Tags: html, forms, post, checkbox

I've got a checkbox, which is default "checked" - Its "POST" enable=true
Second, I've got a checkbox, which is hidden. - This must "POST" enable=false

```
<td>
    <input style="margin-left: -100px" id='checked' type='checkbox' value='true' name='enable'>
    <input id='not_checked'  type='hidden' value='false' name='enable'>
</td>
```

So, if the checkbox have an attribute "checked" - my script is working and  send enable=true.
But if, I doesn't check the box, my script stop working and doesn't send everything.

JS:

```
if(document.getElementById("checked").checked) {
    document.getElementById('not_checked').disabled = true;
}
```

I have taken the example from here:

[Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

Comment: you have `name='enable'` for both this is invalid. when checked it is working because you are disabling the second input and thus effectively having only one item with `name='enable'` to post.

Comment: Can I use <input id='checked' type='checkbox' value='true' style="margin-left: -100px"> and if $("#checked").attr("checked") == "checked" + "&" + "enable=true"; else $("#checked").attr("checked") == "undefined" + "&" + "enable=false";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code .. i think this will do the job

```
<td>
<input id='checked' type='checkbox' value='true' name='checked' style="margin-left: -100px">
<input id='not_checked'  type='hidden' value='false' name='checked'>
</td>
```

Comment: yes, this works.
But, when I edit the "name" of it, its doesn' work anymore.
Its not good, because I need - name="enable"

Comment: if you want to change the name you got to change the id 
i think you want this
' 
<input id='enable' type='checkbox' value='true' name='enable' style="margin-left: -100px">
<input id='not_checked'  type='hidden' value='false' name='enable'>
>

Comment: Can I use <input id='checked' type='checkbox' value='true'  style="margin-left: -100px">

and if $("#checked").attr("checked") == "checked" + "&" + "enable=true";

else $("#checked").attr("checked") == "undefined" + "&" + "enable=false";