# Set an input's default value

Tags: html

I have this input:

```
<input name="giftwrap" type="checkbox"/>
```

However, when the form is submitted and the checkbox has not been checked, I get a `null` rather than a false. **I want a false to be submitted.**

I'm feeling if I give the input a default value of `unchecked` it'll return false rather than `null` as if I tick and then untick the input I get `false`.

So how do I set the input as checked, and how do I set the input as unchecked?

Comment: Why do you want `false` to be submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name=giftwrap]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).next().text(this.value = this.checked);//<-- note its assignment
  }).trigger('change');//<-- trigger on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="giftwrap" type="checkbox" /><span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `checked` attribute:

```
<input name="giftwrap" type="checkbox" checked/>
```

Or maybe you want something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type='hidden' value='0' name='selfdestruct'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='selfdestruct'>
</form>
```

Details: [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

(Read the comments as well.)