# Getting all parameters in Servlets from HTML form

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have aN HTML form where I have check boxes. In the Servlet, I am trying to print all the Parameter names with Values  and In case it has no value i.e it's unchecked , print "BLANK", But surprisingly, the parameter itself is not printed if it has no value/is unchecked.Follows the code:

```
Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();

while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
   String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
   out.print("<tr><td>" + paramName + "</td>\n<td>");
   String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);

   if(paramValues.length == 0)
      out.println("BLANK");      //Why does this not work?

   // Read single valued data
   if (paramValues.length == 1) {
      String paramValue = paramValues[0];
      if (paramValue.length() == 0)
         out.println("<i>No Value</i>");
      else
         out.println(paramValue);
    } 
    else {
      // Read multiple valued data
      out.println("<ul>");
      for(int i=0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
         out.println("<li>" + paramValues[i]);
      }
      out.println("</ul>");
    }
}
      out.println("</tr>\n</table>\n</body></html>");
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: What does: `out.println("-"+paramValue+"-");` instead of `out.println(paramValue);` give you?

Also: if you use if-else, use `{}` it's no problem to omit them if you only have "if". But use {} if you have if else.

Comment: also give the html form and the output you are getting. your error seems to be logically, it can only be answered with above things mentioned. Moreover,  paramValues.length cannot be `0` because it has either `on` or `off` in case of check boxes, which is value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkboxes that are **NOT** checked in a form post are **NOT** sent as parameters. Only *checked* checkboxes are posted in the HTTP POST request.

If you want to post the "unchecked" check boxes, you will have to emply a small hack. Please refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually looking for each property Use JSTL

tags , where you can just specify the java class and with same field name as in form and values directly maps to the bean