# how to get value of unchecked checkbox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox

I am dynamically creating checkbox.

Lets say i add another 2 checkbox by clicking add button which I have written. Now I have

```
 <input id="personalized1"  name="personalized" type="checkbox" class="form-control" />

 <input id="personalized2"  name="personalized" type="checkbox" class="form-control" />

 <input id="personalized3"  name="personalized" type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
```

when I submit I am trying to get a list of both checked and unchecked by doing Request.Form("personalized"); but I get ["ON","ON"]. I am not able to get unchecked value.

Comment: You can simply add `runat="server"` to each one of them, and then within submit method check `personalized2.Checked`. Does it helps you?

Comment: Since I am creating them dynamically on the client side that will not work since I would need to update the control everytime a checkbox is added

Comment: Ahhh, sorry men, didn't get that from the post. JS solution can be considered?

Comment: are you saying I get collect all the values and make a ajax post call ?

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are not included in form submissions as an HTML standard.  You will need to do something like use hidden fields http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked

Comment: Not exactly, but you got the point. On our asp web sites I used to have a hidden field, that was constantly updated with id's of the checkboxes by simple several line jQuery function. And then on submit I just got hidden field value.

Comment: How are you making the checkboxes?  If from c# why not use the Checkbox type?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a hidden input field could be a solution. However, when I did this I created the input fields dynamically like you with the below syntax.

```
<input id='Name' type='checkbox' value='Yes' name='22'>
```

This can work if you can reference the id, the name given above, at the server side. I iterated through the [Request.Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx) data received and checked each key value pair for values of ON, if the value is on then the check box was true. Then I checked for all missing values to determine which where false.

Answer (score 1):

you must use a "trick",
add an input and an hidden field, example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="testbox1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="testbox1" value="0">
```

then you'll receive

testbox1=1 if the box is checked

testbox1=0 if the box is unchecked