# Unchecked checkboxes values to update request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have `show_header` and `show_footer` fields in the database, the value can be 1 or 0.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="show_header" checked="checked" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="show_footer" checked="checked" value="1">
```

Assume `show_header` and `show_footer` is set to 1 in the database and you uncheck the both of them in the form, the request inputs will not contain `show_header` and `show_footer` fields because it is not selected.

So how can I get around this to update `show_header` and `show_footer` to 0 in the database?

**Example :**

```
 $page = Page::where('user_id', 1);

 $page->update($request->all());
```

If you do:

```
dd($request->all())
```

You will not find `show_header` and `show_footer` since checkboxes are not checked, so by doing `$page->update($request->all());` it can't set `show_header` and `show_header` to 0 in the database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I have updated it.

Comment: Use hidden inputs. See - [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

Comment: Show us the output you get from dd()

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back : You check like if show_header and show_footer are set or not in controller using post and simple if not set then set value to 0 and then save it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check before update and set the default value to `0` so if the attributes are not here just set them to `0`:

```
$page = Page::where('user_id', 1);

$data = $request->all();
$data['show_header'] = $request->input('show_header',0);
$data['show_footer'] = $request->input('show_footer',0);

$page->update($data);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller:

```
$page = Page::where('user_id', 1);
if( $request->has('show_header') && $request->show_header == 1 ){
    $page->update(array_add($request->all(), 'show_footer', 0));
}else{
    $page->update(array_add($request->all(), 'show_header', 0));
}
```