# How to populate multiple Checkboxes from to Database?

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a Voice Model where I save all the new voices and each voice has name and language field. My Second Model is Device Model, I want to populate these voices on the Device form view as Checkboxes and let the user to pick one or more than one and save it to related Device as JSON.

Someone - help! :)

How I want to save the voices to the Robot

```
{
  "voice_name":"sample1",
  "voice_language":"English"
}
```

**Voice Model**

```
public $fillable = [
  'name',
  'language'
];

public function devices()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Device');
}
```

**Device Model**

```
public $fillable = [
  'device_name',
  'version',
  'voices'
];

public function voices()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Voice');
}
```

**Robot Form**

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('device_name', 'Device Name:') !!}
{!! Form::text('device_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control') !!}

{!! Form::label('version', 'version:') !!}
{!! Form::text('version', null, ['class' => 'form-control') !!}

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('voices', 'Voices:') !!}

//I want to list all the voices here as Checkboxes
{!! Form::checkbox('voices[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this **selectinput.blade.php**

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{$attr['id']}}" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in"
@foreach ($attr as $attr_key => $attr_value)
    @if ($attr_key == 'disabled')
        @if($attr_value == 'disabled')
            disabled="disabled"
        @endif
    @else
        @if ($attr_key == 'readonly')
            @if($attr_value == 'readonly')
                readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"
            @endif
        @else
            {{$attr_key}}="{{$attr_value}}"
        @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
    @if ($val=="1")
        checked
    @endif
    @if (isset($attr['id']))
        name="{{ $attr['id'] }}"
    @endif value="1">
@if (isset($attr['id']))
    <label for="{{ $attr['id'] }}" >
        {{ $label }}
    </label>
@endif
```

Where there are 2 checkboxes as a kind of hack to always send the checkbox value, even if it's unchecked, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked).

Comment: Can I ask you one question? now when I create New Device and I check multiple Checkboxes then I am storing new Device info but at the same time I want to save **Device_id** and **Voice_id** to the pivot table?

Comment: Can you please ask that in a new question? I need more explaination :)

Comment: Sure and I will share the link with you :)

Comment: Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532629/how-to-save-multiple-checkboxes-value-into-pivot-table