# How to save multiple Checkboxes value into Pivot Table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models with Many-to-Many Relation when I create new Device and check multiple Checkboxes I want to save multiple voices_id with Device_id into the Pivot Table **device_voice**

Device Controller ( I am facing this error Undefined variable: selectedVoice in Edit function )

```
public function create()
{
    $this->authorize("create", Device::class);

    $voice_list = Voice::all();

    return view('devices.create')
        ->with('voice_list', $voice_list);
}

public function store(CreateDeviceRequest $request)
{
    $this->authorize("create", Device::class);

    $input = $request->all();
    $voices_checkbox = $input['voice'];

    $device = $this->deviceRepository->create($input);

    //Device Id and Selected voices is Saved Successfully 
    $device ->voices()->sync($voices_checkbox);

    Flash::success('Device saved successfully.');

    return redirect(route('devices.index'));
}
public function edit($id)
{
    $device = $this->deviceRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    $this->authorize("update", $device);

    $voice_list    = Voice::all();

    // Here I am getting Device's checked voices, but sinces I am sharing      the same Fields Blade with Create and Edit I get this error 
    //Undefined variable: selectedVoice 
    $selectedVoice = $device->voices->pluck("id")->toArray();

    if (empty($device)) {
        Flash::error('Device not found');

        return redirect(route('devices.index'));
    }

    return view('devices.edit')
          ->with('device', $device)
          ->with('voice_list', $voice_list)
          ->with('selectedVoice', $selectedVoice);
}
```

This is My Fields for Both Create and Edit Views

```
<!-- Device Number Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('device_number', 'Device Number:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('device_number', null) !!}
</div>

<!-- Batch Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('device_name', 'Device Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('device_name', null) !!}
</div>

<!-- Batch Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('voices_id', 'Voices:') !!}

    @foreach ($voice_list as $voice)
        {!! Form::checkbox('voice[]', $voice->id, in_array($voice->id, $selectedVoice)) !!}
        {!! Form::label('voice', $voice->name) !!}
    @endforeach

</div>

<!-- Version Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('version', 'Version:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('version', null) !!}
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just put them all in their own form? That way you can handle them 1 by 1 in laravel. You can submit them at the same time using javascript (ajax)

Comment: @thomas-moors I solve too as well but there another problem I got headache hehe :D can you check my codes again :)

Comment: Can you describe better what input you give and what you expect to happen please. " I want to save multiple voices_id with Device_id into the Pivot Table device_voice" is not clear for me.

Comment: " I want to save multiple voices_id with Device_id into the Pivot Table device_voice " This one is solve , can you please check Create and Edit Functions with the Fields :) @thomas-moors

Comment: Are you hitting the right urls? `devices/create` and `devices//{device-id}/edit`? Are your routes registered right?

Comment: Everything thing is fine, you can that the error in fields blade because in Editing method I have selectedVoice variable but In Create Method I don't and as I said they both sharing the same fields methods, got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`sync()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method:

```
$device->voices()->sync($request->voices);
```

Comment: Now it's saving the voices id together with the Device id but There is another problem which is that I am sharing the same Fields Blade file for the Create and Edit not saving the selected Checkboxes, Why? I will update my codes @alexey-mezenin