# I can't get my array checkbox values in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, checkbox

I can't find out why this isn't working so please don't shred me for asking this question although it's been answered. I have a HTML array of checkboxes and I'd like to get the value of what is checked. I'm getting the questions via a cURL request.

I've tried several combinations of changing variable names, adding index values, using the

```
foreach ($var1 as $var1 => $value)
```

and still nothing.

PHP to display the questions:

```
      $exquest = curl_exec($ch); 
      curl_close($ch);
      $exquest = json_decode($exquest, true); 

      $numOfQuests = $exquest["questcount"]; 

      for ($i=0; $i<$numOfQuests; $i++) 
      {
      echo "<input type='checkbox' name='q[]' value='" . $exquest['question$i'] . "'> " . $exquest["question$i"] . "<br /><br />";
      }
```

PHP to collect checked questions:

```
if(is_array($_POST['q'])){
    foreach($_POST['q'] as $value){
  print_r($value);
  var_dump($value);
      }
   }
```

OUTPUT:

The outputs I've gotten thus far are either "Array" repeated the number of times equal to the number of boxes checked, or [0]=> 0, [1] => [1], etc but even then it only goes by total number checked not the sequence (i.e index 0, 2, and 4) it'll always come back 0,1,2 etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked

Comment: unchecked checkboxes do not submit any value.

Comment: What you're getting is the expected output, What you need to change in that ?

Comment: I would expect it to return the value of what's stored on the checkbox line no? Is it just my misunderstanding of checkboxes and html? I thought if you had *checkbox* > "foo", if i was checked it could return "foo"

Comment: Yeah, I started to suspect that it wasn't stored or returning correctly from the db. It posted blank as per your suggesting which will help narrow it down. Thank you!

Comment: Please do not add voting advice or commentary to your posts - keep them succinct and if you hang around here, and if you post good questions, you will get more upvotes than down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ryan Vincent suggested, by checking `var_dump($_POST);` I determined that nothing was being sent from one page to the other aside form the N number of checked boxes."

Solution: I was missing the $i in q[] for name and id. Thanks all!

```
     echo "<input type='checkbox' name='q[$i]' id='q[$i]' value='" . $exquest["question$i"] . "'> " . $exquest["question$i"] . "<br /><br />"
```