# Checkbox is not taking unchecked value in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

In checkbox when I selected it then value(1) is going to database but when I am not selected Zero(0) is not going to DB and error is like A

> Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1048 Column 'paid' cannot be
>   null
>
> INSERT INTO `topic` (`title`, `description`, `content`, `attachment`,
>   `courseId`, `sectionId`, `type`, `paid`) VALUES ('Mysql Unit 1',
>   'Mysql unit description', 'video1.mp4', 'upload.mp4', '292', '83',
>   'unit', NULL)
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/ci3/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

### addunit.php

```
 <td>
    <div class="form-item form-checkbox checkbox-style">
    <input type="checkbox" id="make" name="free" value="1">
       <label for="make">
          <i class="icon-checkbox icon md-check-1"></i>
          Make this Unit as Free
       </label>
    </div>
 </td>
```

[image: checkbox]

Comment: when unchecked nothing related to checkbox gets submitted, one alternative is to use hidden inputs

Comment: as in, set a hidden in the form, if checkbox is checked, ignore hidden, otherwise refer to the hidden input value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox doesn't return any value if it is unchecked? 
So, if you want such to check whether it was checked or not you better use the `isset` method of PHP. For example:

`$isFree = isset($_POST['free']`

Then use this `$isFree` variable to insert into DB.