# Retain checkbox values on submit

Tags: php, checkbox

Below is the code for the checkbox

```
foreach($fruits as $key=>$values) {
 echo "<td bgcolor=\"#EAEAEA\" style=\"color:#003399\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"fruits[]\" value='$fruits[$key]'>$fruits[$key]</td>";
```

How can i retain the values selected once i click submit?

Comment: You could set the values to sessions, check if the sessions are set on page load and echo the session filled check-boxes if they are else echo the original

Comment: Could you share the code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes don't use value attributes. You have the attribute `checked='checked'` or simply `checked` which means it's selected. You then get a $_POST array where if you have the checkboxes checked, they will show up with the names in the keys, but if not checked, they will not be submitted at all. So you would need to make hidden fields if you really want to pass these unchecked checkboxes as well. See this post on the details of how to accomplish it: [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

Comment: Making a correction I think someone mentioned here before checkboxes actually have value attributes which will be passed as the value associated with the key just like text input boxes. Though only checked ones will be submitted.