# Post the checkboxes in an array that are unchecked

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I want to get all values from a set of checkboxes via POST - also the ones that return false. For a single checkbox there is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked). It's hacky but it does at least not require Javascript. But how about this

```
<input name="link[]" type="checkbox"/>
<input name="link[]" type="checkbox"/>
...
```

A similiar solution as the one suggested in the other post would not work, because it keeps iterating:

```
<input name="link[]" type="hidden"/>    <!-- 0 -->
<input name="link[]" type="checkbox"/>  <!-- 1 -->
<input name="link[]" type="hidden"/>    <!-- 2 -->
<input name="link[]" type="checkbox"/>  <!-- 3 -->
...
```

Comment: You want the values of the UNCHECKED checkboxes submitted via POST?

Comment: I want all values, so that it matches the Array returned by the text-input-field "name". If I only get the checked ones there is no way to determine which checkbox is actually checked.

Comment: That is completely the wrong approach. You are not using the checkboxes correctly.

Comment: why not? I need a boolean value if the link should be opened in a new tab or not. Checkboxes seem more appropriate then select-Tags.

Comment: Why not? Because this is not how checkboxes work. If you are trying to use checkboxes for links, then how does the POST come into play?

Answer (score 2):

The one other way I can think of is explicitly giving them indexes

```
<input name="link[0]" type="hidden"/> 
<input name="link[0]" type="checkbox"/>  
<input name="link[1]" type="hidden"/>   
<input name="link[1]" type="checkbox"/>
<input name="link[2]" type="hidden"/>
<input name="link[2]" type="checkbox"/>
```

Or you could do this, without using hidden inputs:

```
<input name="link[0]" type="checkbox"/>  
<input name="link[1]" type="checkbox"/>
<input name="link[2]" type="checkbox"/>
```

Then check for missing array indexes server-side.

Comment: I dont have the possibility to index the 'name' .So ,Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

When a form is submitted, all the form elements that have a `name` attribute specified for them submit their `name` and their `value`. With most form elements, the `value` comes from what the user inputs.

When you submit a form that has radio buttons and/or checkboxes in it, only the name/value pairs form the checked checkbox or radio button is submitted. This way, your form processing code doesn't have to sort out which buttons/boxes were checked. A consequence of this however, is that both checkboxes and radio buttons must have a `value` set for their `value` attribute. This value is how you will know which button/box was selected (receiving a name/value pair of `checkbox4=true` doesn't really tell you much.)

In the following code, we will know which checkboxes were checked just by looking at the data submitted to the form's `action` which checkboxes were checked and what the meaning of those checks were:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkStudent1" value="Mary"> Mary
<input type="checkbox" name="chkStudent2"  value="John"> John
<input type="checkbox" name="chkStudent3"  value="Joe"> Joe
```

Now, when the form is submitted, and let's say you check the second checkbox, the name/value pair of `chkStudent2=John` will be submitted. Your form processing code will know exactly which element was checked and the corresponding data will be available to that code.