# Check Box in Express JS

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, checkbox

If i have a form input like this :

**home.ejs**

```
<form action="/route" method="post>
<% for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ %>
<input type="checkbox" name="mytext">
<% }; %>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**router.js**

```
router.post('/route',function (req, res) {
var data = req.body.checkbox;
console.log(data);
});
```

If i check the [0], [1], [3] :

The Result:
[ 'on', 'on', 'on' ]

Expectation:
[ 'on', 'on', ' ', 'on', ' ']

Is there any explanation why the result only 3 not 5? and how to fix it? I want to get all the value (checked or not checked).

Thank you

Comment: Without javascript ?

Comment: try req.body.mytext

Comment: That is the normal behavior of submitting a form with checkboxes. The response will only have those that were checked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post the checkboxes that are unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

Comment: yes, with out javascript. directly send to route, and get all the data using req.body @EvyatarMeged

Comment: still same, the result still [ 'on', 'on', 'on' ].
i can't identify which id already checked on the form @zb22

Comment: did i must to use jquery to get all data and the list form before send to server or just send directly form data to server ? @Mikey