# PHP get the table data row input value using loop

Tags: php, html

I am having a issue in getting the correct value from the `table`.

**The issue I encountered:**

- When I choose the second `checkbox` the and input a `quantity`, it is **Undefined offset: 0**

But the value of the `checkbox` is working and correct.

What I am expecting is when I choose the second or other `checkbox` (exclude first `checkbox`), I should get the value of that input field.

**HTML**

```
<?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="<?php echo $row->items_id; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->item_name; ?></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="process" class="btn btn-primary" value="Process">
```

**PHP**

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$products = $_POST['products'];
$count_selected = count($products);

for($i=0; $i< $count_selected; $i++){
    var_dump($quantity[$i]); exit;
}
```

[image: sample image of the view]

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($quantity)`  ?

Comment: `$row->items_id`? Is that correct? You sure it's not `$row->item_id`?

Comment: The problem with checkboxes is that an unchecked one submits no value so your `$_POST['products']` and `$_POST['quantity']` arrays may have different lengths.

Comment: @qskane, it has an error `Undefined offset: 0` below to that error it has a value of `NULL`

Comment: @Phil, variable in `HTML` is correct. As you said that, it may the main issue. Can you give some idea on how I can get the value of the table row if the specific checkbox is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with checkboxes is that an unchecked one submits no value so your `$_POST['products']` and `$_POST['quantity']` arrays may have different lengths.

I'd combine using a [hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992745/283366) with specific array indexes.

For example

```php
<?php foreach($results as $row) : ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="products[<?= $row->items_id ?>]" value="0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="products[<?= $row->items_id ?>]" value="1">
    </td>
    <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row->item_name) ?></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="quantity[<?= $row->items_id ?>]" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

---

Then the arrays will have the same indexes and you can iterate them with a `foreach`

```php
foreach ($_POST['products'] as $itemId => $checked) {
    // $checked represents the state of the checkbox
    // you can access quantity via $_POST['quantity'][$itemId]
}
```

You could even create a nice filtered array of quantities via

```
$selections = $_POST['products'];
$quantities = array_filter($_POST['quantity', function($itemId) use ($selections) {
    return $selections[$itemId];
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: I will try what you suggest. As soon I get the correct answer related to what you answer, I will get back to you on this. I really appreciate it. Thank.

Comment: Sorry took too long, anyway I got it working by following your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

first, define array variable.
    $products =array( );
    $quantity=array( );
other wise every thing seems fine.

Comment: OP already has defined `$products` and `$quantity`. Why would they need to first define them as empty arrays?