# How to post "all" checkbox values in google app script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I created a web app through google app script, which could generate a table of data for users to select for calculation. So I would generate a table with values and checkboxes through google sheet.(the table size may differ between users). 
There is my sample code.

```
<form role="qryForm" method="post" action="<?!= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>">
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
 <table>
   <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="changeName(this)" name="uncheck" value ="100"></td>
        <td>100</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="changeName(this)" name="uncheck" value ="200"></td>
        <td>200</td>
   </tr>

 </table>
</form>
```

When the checkbox is clicked, a small function will change the name of input to be "checked".

However, when the submit button is pressed, only the checked parameter is returned to the server. I looked at the event object (e.parameters), it dose not return the values under the name of "uncheck"

I am expecting to get something like: check:[1,2,3,4], uncheck:[5,6,7,8]

How do I get it down? or how do I get the values of all checkboxes in google appscript?

Comment: Hello! May I ask, why are you even changing the "name" of your checkboxes? Please bear in mind that the [name attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefname) should never be repeated within a form (each element should have its distinct `name`)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. It is a mistake.

Comment: No worries. After correcting this, do you still have issues? If so, kindly update your original question with any issue you may have (if it is relevant to the original question)

Comment: Unfortunately, It did not solve my problem. I use auto generated input name attribute, so that every name attribute is different. The form still only returned values that has been checked. Like this :

Comment: {parameter={flag=true, check=2}, contextPath=, contentLength=29, queryString=, parameters={flag=[true], check=[2, 3]}, postData=FileUpload} .      

the "flag" is another Input named flag outside the form, and the "check" are those checkboxes that have been clicked

Answer (score 0):

From the [W3C HTML 4 guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html):

> Checkboxes (and radio buttons) are on/off switches that may be toggled by the user. A switch is "on" when the control element's checked attribute is set. When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become successful.

Essentially - unchecked checkboxes are not sent along with the form, only the checked ones.

There are many workarounds which you may learn about here: [POST unchecked HTML checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-unchecked-html-checkboxes)