# Define values for checkbox answer

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a simple contact form, but I have difficulty to understand how checkbox works. This is the part I have a problem:

HTML:

```
<input name="selection" type="checkbox">
```

PHP:

```
$selection = $_POST['selection'];
$mail->Body = "
    Answer is ".$_POST["selection"]."
"
```

Once the checkbox is clicked and the form is submitted, the function above prints "Answer is on" in the e-mail.
How can I print "Answer is Positive" once checkbox is clicked, and "Answer is Negative" when checkbox is not clicked in a simple way?

Comment: Read on how the value is handled https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value

Comment: `$selection = isset($_POST['selection']) ? "Positive" : "Negative";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I didn't know that defining a custom positive value for a checkbox is so simple:

HTML

```
<input name="selection" type="checkbox" value="Write here what you want to post when the checkbox is checked">
```

As for posting the negative value, I realized that it's not that necessary for my project. For those who wonder how, all alternatives are explained here:

[POST unchecked HTML checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-unchecked-html-checkboxes)