# Form not returning full array of checkbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

When trying to get the values from checkbox inputs I keep getting only the true values. For example, if N of the checkboxes are selected, it would return something like "IsCorrect: [True, ...](N times). What I'm looking for is [True, False, True] if the first/third checkbox are selected and the second is not.

What's really throwing me is that the text fields associated with the answers are updating as expected.

This is the first time I've used razor pages, so if I'm missing something glaringly obvious please let me know. I'd really like to do this the right way.

Here's the view:

```
@foreach(var question in Model.Questions)
{
  <form method="post">
    ...
        <button 
          asp-page-handler="UpdateQuestion" 
          asp-route-question="@question"
          asp-route-questionId="@question.Id"
        >
          Update
        </button>
     ...
      <label>Question</label>
      <div>
        <input 
          asp-for="@question.Text" 
          name="question"
        />
      ...
      <div>Mark Correct</div>
      <div>Answers</div>
          @if(question.Answers != null)
          {
          @foreach(var answer in question.Answers)
            {
              <div>
                  <input 
                      name="answer"
                      asp-for="@answer.Text"
                  />
                  <input 
                      type="checkbox"
                      asp-for="@answer.IsCorrect"
                      name="isCorrect"
                  />
              </div>
            }
          }
    </div>
  </form>
}
```

Controller:

```
...
[BindProperty]
public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; } = default!;
...
public IActionResult OnPostUpdateQuestion([FromForm] Question question, Guid questionId)
{
    var answers = Request.Form["answer"];
    var isCorrect = Request.Form["isCorrect"];

    question.Text = Request.Form["question"];
    question.Id = questionId;

    _service.UpdateQuestionAndAnswers(question, answers, isCorrect);
    return RedirectToAction("Get");
}
```

And models? Idk, could that impact this?

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Learning.Models;
public class Question
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public required string Text { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Answer>? Answers { get; set; }
  public Boolean IsPracticeQuestion { get; set; } = true;
  public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
  public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Learning.Models;
public class Answer
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public required string Text { get; set; }
  public required bool IsCorrect { get; set; } = true;
  [JsonIgnore]
  public Question Question { get; set; } = default!;
  public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
  public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a Razor thing, it's just how checkbox inputs work in HTML.  Only checked values are sent to the server.  While not necessarily a duplicate, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1809494/328193) offers approaches to send all of your values to the server.

Comment: Hmmm I looked at that post in my search -- the asp-for helper automatically sets up a hidden input field and sets it the correct initial value. I'm wondering if I need to manually update those values with some client side scripting.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know the helpers automatically added that (for this exact reason, I imagine).  Which makes it odd that it's a problem in the first place.  You might focus some specific debugging outside the scope of ASP.NET and look into the client-side markup and resulting form post request in the browser's development tools.  I'd be curious what the actual HTML is for one of the errant fields and what is being posted to the server.

Comment: A few paths down that link you sent helped me arrive at a temporary (and probably not ideal) solution of a script to put the values into an array, put it into a string, and have the form pick up on it. Definitely not ideal, but I appreciate the brain power add to this :D