# How to preSelect an html dropdown list with php?

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu, return, html-select

I am trying to get the option selected using PHP, but I ran out of ideas!

Below is the code I have tried until now:

```
<select>
<option value="1">Yes</options>
<option value="2">No</options>
<option value="3">Fine</options>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="go" name="go">
```

So, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 16):

Programmers are lazy...er....efficient....I'd do it like so:

```php
<select><?php
    $the_key = 1; // or whatever you want
    foreach(array(
        1 => 'Yes',
        2 => 'No',
        3 => 'Fine',
    ) as $key => $val){
        ?><option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"<?php
            if($key==$the_key)echo ' selected="selected"';
        ?>><?php echo $val; ?></option><?php
    }
?></select>
<input type="text" value="" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="go" name="go">
```

Comment: This is the only solution that addresses a select with tens or hundreds of options.  +1

Comment: @Wes how does it addresses hundreds of options?? You would need to type all those out in the foreach.......

Comment: @YunfeiChen You can build the array of options in another script by looping through your data and then use that variable in the foreach above.

Comment: @wes how is that better, you would still need to type all the options in an array???

Comment: @wes still need to type at several hundred elements...... Don't see how that is better??

Answer (score 5):

```
<select>
<option value="1" <?php if ($myVar==1) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Yes</options>
<option value="2" <?php if ($myVar==2) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>No</options>
<option value="3" <?php if ($myVar==3) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Fine</options>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="go" name="go">
```

This is a very simple and straightforward way, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I beat you by one second mister!:P

Comment: @Iznogood  I think you mean the other way.. Mouseover your answer's timestamp says 17:14:48, whereas over Bart's answer, it says 17:14:47 :)

Comment: Well @Davinder You're 5 years late! :-)

Comment: You get undefined variable $myvar error.....

Answer (score 5):

you can use this..

```
<select name="select_name">
    <option value="1"<?php echo(isset($_POST['select_name'])&&($_POST['select_name']=='1')?' selected="selected"':'');?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="2"<?php echo(isset($_POST['select_name'])&&($_POST['select_name']=='2')?' selected="selected"':'');?>>No</option>
    <option value="3"<?php echo(isset($_POST['select_name'])&&($_POST['select_name']=='3')?' selected="selected"':'');?>>Fine</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all give a name to your select. Then do:

```
<select name="my_select">
<option value="1" <?= ($_POST['my_select'] == "1")? "selected":"";?>>Yes</options>
<option value="2" <?= ($_POST['my_select'] == "2")? "selected":"";?>>No</options>
<option value="3" <?= ($_POST['my_select'] == "3")? "selected":"";?>>Fine</options>
</select>
```

What that does is check if what was selected is the same for each and when its found echo "selected".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using an array to create your `select` form input. 
In that case, use an array:

```
<?php
    $selected = array( $_REQUEST['yesnofine'] => 'selected="selected"' );
    $fields = array(1 => 'Yes', 2 => 'No', 3 => 'Fine');
 ?>
  <select name=‘yesnofine'>
 <?php foreach ($fields as $k => $v): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $k;?>" <?php @print($selected[$k]);?>><?php echo $v;?></options>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
```

If not, you may just unroll the above loop, and still use an array.

```
 <option value="1" <?php @print($selected[$k]);?>>Yes</options>
 <option value="2" <?php @print($selected[$k]);?>>No</options>
 <option value="3" <?php @print($selected[$k]);?>>Fine</options>
```

Notes that I don't know:

- how you are naming your input, so I made up a name for it.
- which way you are handling your form input on server side, I used `$_REQUEST`,

You will have to adapt the code to match requirements of the framework you are using, if any.

Also, it is customary in many frameworks to use [the alternative syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146756/php-alternative-syntax-vs-curly-bracket) in view dedicated scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I use inline if's

```
($_POST['category'] == $data['id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : false)
```

Comment: For the record, "inline if's" are actually known as the "ternary operator".

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 php files and i made this, and it works.
(this is an example) the first code is from the one file and the second code from two file.

```
<form action="two.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="submit" name="one"/>
<select name="numbers">
<option value="1"> 1 </option>
<option value="2"> 2 </option>
<option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>
</form>



if(isset ($_POST['one']))
{

if($_POST['numbers']=='1')
{
$a='1' ;
}
else if($_POST['numbers']=='2')
{
$a='2' ;
{
else if ($_POST['numbers']=='3')
{
$a='3' ;
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer is not relevant for particular recepient, but maybe useful for others.
I had similiar issue with 'selecting' right 'option' by value returned from database. 
I solved it by adding additional  tag with applied display:none.

```
<?php
$status =  "NOT_ON_LIST";

$text = "<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id=\"statuses\">
   <option value=\"status\" selected=\"selected\" style=\"display:none\">$status</option>
   <option value=\"status\">OK</option>
   <option value=\"status\">DOWN</option>
   <option value=\"status\">UNKNOWN</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>";

print $text;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution that I've came up with:

```
<form name = "form1" id = "form1" action = "#" method = "post">
  <select name = "DropDownList1" id = "DropDownList1">
<?php
$arr = array('Yes', 'No', 'Fine' ); // create array so looping is easier
for( $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++ ) // loop starts at first value and ends at last value
{
  $selected = ''; // keep selected at nothing
  if( isset( $_POST['go'] ) ) // check if form was submitted
  {
    if( $_POST['DropDownList1'] == $i ) // if the value of the dropdownlist is equal to the looped variable
    {
      $selected = 'selected = "selected"'; // if is equal, set selected = "selected"
    }
  }
  // note: if value is not equal, selected stays defaulted to nothing as explained earlier
  echo '<option value = "' . $i . '"' . $selected . '>' . $arr[$i] . '</option>'; // echo the option element to the page using the $selected variable
}
?>
  </select> <!-- finish the form in html -->
  <input type="text" value="" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="go" name="go">
</form>
```

The code I have works as long as the values are integers in some numeric order ( ascending or descending ). What it does is starts the dropdownlist in html, and adds each option element in php code. It will not work if you have random values though, i.e: 1, 4, 2, 7, 6. Each value must be unique.

Comment: You couldn't make it any more inefficient:
**1.** Check for `$_POST['go']` only once, not on each iteration in the loop **2.** Your loop doesn't take care of the changes in the array, at least use `count($arr)` not a hard-coded number. **3.** PHP's `foreach()` loop automatically handles iterating through an array and retrieving the keys and values - so you don't have to have your own increment index.