# Help needed with using jquery to check checkboxes from php array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a php array which I'm trying to get jQuery to check those checkboxes, but I can't seem to get it working. My php array name is "toCheck" which is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
```

0,3,4 are the checkboxes I need checked. Here's my checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="correct[0]" id="correct" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="correct[1]" id="correct" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="correct[2]" id="correct" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="correct[3]" id="correct" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="correct[4]" id="correct" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="correct[5]" id="correct" value="5" />
```

If someone could point out what jQuery to use to make these checkboxes selected, that would be great!

```
<?php foreach($toCheck as $checkMe) { ?>
//i'm assuming my jquery goes here but I can't get it working
<?php }; ?>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. `id` values must be **unique** within a document ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#concept-id)).

That said, ignoring the `id` values, you could use this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/odome3)):

```
$(':checkbox[name^=correct]').each(function() {
    switch (this.value) {
        case "0":
        case "3":
        case "4":
            this.checked = true;
            break;
     }
});
```

That uses a CSS3 substring selector (jQuery supports nearly all of CSS3) on the `name` attribute to select any checkbox with a name starting with `correct`, and then uses jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through them. Then we set the `checked` property on the ones with the desired `value`.

You could also do it with a longer selector and without the loop ([live example](http://jsbin.com/odome3/2)):

```
$(':checkbox[name^=correct][value=0], :checkbox[name^=correct][value=3], :checkbox[name^=correct][value=4]').attr('checked', true);
```

**Update**: Re-reading your question, it looks like you might need to do this more dynamically:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    var boxes = $(); // Assumes jQuery 1.4 or higher
<?php foreach($toCheck as $checkMe) { ?>
    echo "boxes.add(':checkbox[name=^=correct][value=" . $toCheck . "]');";
<?php }; ?>
    boxes.attr('checked', true);
})();
</script>
```

...which would generate:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    var boxes = $(); // Assumes jQuery 1.4 or higher
    boxes.add(':checkbox[name=^=correct][value=0]');
    boxes.add(':checkbox[name=^=correct][value=3]');
    boxes.add(':checkbox[name=^=correct][value=4]');
    boxes.attr('checked', true);
})();
</script>
```

...which would check the relevant boxes. But it wouldn't be very efficient (all of that document traversal), better off using PHP to combine the values into a selector or `switch` as shown above.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll fix up my ids and play with the above :)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that browsers don't submit unchecked checkboxes.

See [Submit an HTML form with empty checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476426/submit-an-html-form-with-empty-checkboxes) for more.