# jqGrid checkbox values not bound

Tags: grails, jqgrid, checkbox

Using jqGrid (4.4) with Grails (2.0.3).

I have a grid with checkbox columns.  Data is local and not using Grails editUrl property to submit data.  I'm submitting the entire page to the backend controller using a regular submit button.

Here's the rub ...
Say the grid contains 5 rows and the 5 checkboxes (indexes 0-4) have values of (true, false, true, true, false).  What gets to the controller via the params map is an array of 3 checkbox values, all true with indexes 0, 1, 2.  So, only the 'true' values are passed to the controller, but I have no idea which row they belong to.

Please advise.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not specific to grails, this is just a common html/webdevelopment question.

1. Unchecked checkboxes aren't sent to the server when form is submitted.
2. And you dont have to keep the submitted value of a checkbox to true, you can use any custom value (the value attribute) and then on server you can identify which checkboxes where checked based on the values

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476426/submit-an-html-form-with-empty-checkboxes) as well

Comment: Thanks.  Makes sense, now.  The grails <g:checkbox> tag renders an html checkbox input as well as a hidden tag (with a '_' prefix) to submit the 'off' value.  So, you get values in both cases.  However, I'm not using the <g:checkbox> tag in this case, so what I was used to was not happening.  Thanks again.