# Razor generating two input tags for the same element

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I have a simple login form, which I am rendering through Razor like this -

```
<div class="row">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EMail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "E-Mail" })
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", value="1", @checked = "1"})
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="signinbutton" value="Sign In" />
</div>
```

It is rendering properly on page, but when I try to serialize it, this is the output -

```
EMail=Sam&Password=sam&RememberMe=1&RememberMe=false
```

`RememberMe` is serialized two times above.

When I digged into the generated html, the input field is generated twice -

```
<input checked="1" data-val="true" data-val-required="The RememberMe field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false">
```

it looks weird. I am not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is intentional because an empty checkbox will not be submitted as anything. To submit a false value, if the checkbox is not checked, the hidden input will be read.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476581/1730461) for more.

Comment: Though I still am confused as to why this has to be like this, I have added my custom function to serialize the form. Thanks.