# What is the Laravel way to check if the POST Request has a field left empty?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, postdata

The requirement was to update user roles. The role can be empty(left blank), one, or more than one as provided in the form field `roles[]`.

Here is the view form:

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
  <div class="checkbox">
     <label><input name="roles[]" type="checkbox" value="{{$role->id}}" {{ $user->roles->contains($role->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}>{{$role->name}}</label>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

The condition inside **UserController::update()** is:

```
if ($request->roles) {
    // update user roles
}
```

Everything works fine except for one case. Sometimes the user has to stay without any role.

`if($request->roles)`, `isset($request->roles)`, and `!empty($request->roles)` .. are all giving the same old fashioned reply(`null`, `''`, `true/flase`).

Case: *when there is one or more role(s) assigned*:

```
  +request: ParameterBag {#41 ▼
    #parameters: array:6 [▼
      "_method" => "PUT"
      "_token" => "a8oIPQFBMbhjanikX8v83qeOcfRE0N4UKTcTQDig"
      "name" => "New User Name"
      "email" => "newuser@testserver.asap"
      "password" => ""
      "roles" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "2"
        1 => "3"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Case: *when there no role assigned OR need to remove(detach) the previously assigned role*:

```
  +request: ParameterBag {#41 ▼
    #parameters: array:5 [▼
      "_method" => "PUT"
      "_token" => "a8oIPQFBMbhjanikX8v83qeOcfRE0N4UKTcTQDig"
      "name" => "New User Name"
      "email" => "newuser@testserver.asap"
      "password" => ""
    ]
  }
```

So the question (requirement) is:

**How to differentiate when the field value of an HTML Post form has been submitted as empty(unchecked here) or if there was no such a field in the view form?**
**Is there an eloquent* way in Laravel to find/list the form fileds from the `Request` object?**

[PS: Trying another hidden field or do some frontend jQuery will not be appreciated]

Comment: I think isset($request->roles) works fine to check whether there is any role or not submitted from the form

Comment: have you try  ? $request->has('roles')

Comment: `$request->has('roles') ` is giving the same result!

Comment: `isset($request->roles)` says true or false, how do I know when there was a field but still left empty? @ashokpoudel

Comment: Please remember to check an answer as correct so the question is closed and other users can identify the answer as a solution to their problem. Thank you.

Comment: None of them from the core functions meet the requirement. Not even the server variable `$_POST` contains all form fields.
There is a chance that:`$request->filled('roles')` may help for 5.5+ users but not others. Another logic (*i.e, by taking the input value as an array*) helped to to solve my custom requirement and still the question remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to identify this problem in the design of your application.

> How to differentiate when the field value of an HTML Post form has been submitted as empty(unchecked here) or if there was no such a field in the view form? Is there an eloquent* way in Laravel to find/list the form fileds from the Request object?

When does that form should not have a `roles[]` field? You should have a marker that will tell your application that this form doesn't have a `roles[]` field.

Something like, when this form is used when an ordinary user is updating his/her profile, he/she will not be able to update his/her roles.

Because your problem is indeed the default behavior of forms, as answered in this question: [Submit an HTML form with empty checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476426/submit-an-html-form-with-empty-checkboxes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

So there will be a different process for forms which **DO NOT HAVE** have a roles field and different process for forms which **DO HAVE** a roles field.

To add to your implementation, you can retrieve the roles field like this:

```
$roles = $request->input('roles', []);
```

After which you can just use `sync` to the relationship method of your model.

```
$user->roles()->sync($roles);
```

Comment: Yes that helps, `$request->input('roles', [])` will do it.

Comment: There is no such a case that: *the form should not have roles[]*. I had no other way but to ask such a question.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the laravel request methods `has()` or `filled()`, `has` checks if the parameter is present and `filled` checks it's present **and** filled:

```
if ($request->has('roles')) {
    //
}
```

or

```
if ($request->filled('roles')) {
    //
}
```

Check [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input) for further details on retrieving input from the request object.

**EDIT**

Since you are using Laravel 5.2 the following rules apply:

- The `has()` method checks the parameter is present **and** filled.
- The `exists()` method checks the parameted is present.

Check [the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L261) on the repo for more information.

Comment: `filled()` is not available for versions below 5.5. I think that is the proper way to do it. Unfortunately I still use Laravel 5.2. `$request->has('roles')` is the same as `isset($request->roles)`

Comment: @EazySam I've updated the answer adding the 5.2 information :)

Answer (score 3):

For this you have [validations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation), seems that you need the `roles` field to be `required` and `exists`(to map to a certain table)

You just need to make the validator via artisan command and inject it in the controller method, check out the docs.

ex:
`php artisan make:request MyCustomRequest`
Then you should have a request file under: `App\Http\Requests`
You need to set the validation rules as described above:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MyCustomRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'rules' =>'required|exists:tour_roles_table,id'
        ];
    }
}
```

Then you can use inject it in your desired method:

```
class UserController extends Controller {
[...]
    public function update(MyCustomRequest $req)
    {
     [...]
     //at this point validation was successfull, by default Laravel will redirect back with error messages, which can be customized in your request object
    }
[...]
}
```

Comment: This definitely seems like a job for validation.

Comment: In this case roles are optional, so require them via validation would not be the best solution.

Comment: @Asur Tou can set fields to be optional as well if OP wants via the `sometimes` rule

Comment: `required` and `exist` both don't help (

Comment: Yes of course, but he needs to add logic to the condition so the only way you could do that with validation is checking the `errorsBag`, which IMO would add unnecessary complexity to a pretty simple problem

Comment: Don't help in what way?

Comment: I think a validation is in order because one can have inconsistent data from the start and would need to validate before persisting the request, this is my opinion

Comment: @ka_lin Don't help to check a condition that: if the form has a field and that was left empty.

Comment: If a user doesn't have any roles you should send an empty `roles` parameter to be consistent

Answer (score 1):

try if(empty())

```
$check = request::get('roles');

if(empty($checkbox)){
  //if checkbox have a empty value do ...
}else{
  //if checkbox have not empty value do .. 
}
```

for more information click http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Yes/No-True/False! `empty()`, `isset()` are all giving the same result here.

Answer (score 0):

We were just having issues checking this. We tried everything in this question and nothing worked, but finally we found a solution:

```
array_key_exists($request->notes)
```